# Laravel doesn't show custom Blade view for HTTP status 403

Tags: php, laravel

According to Laravel's [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/errors#custom-http-error-pages), you may display a custom Blade view for a given HTTP response by adding said view to resources/views/errors and naming the file [httpcode].blade.php. I've done this for 404 errors and Laravel shows this view whenever a 404 error is encountered. However, when a 403 error is encountered, Laravel instead shows the default, ugly Apache 403 "Forbidden" error page.

My "master" Blade layout (master.blade.php):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="SQLess is a database management application.">
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">
    @stack('css-extras')
    @stack('scripts-extras')
</head>
<body>
@yield('content')
</body>
</html>
```

My custom 403 layout (403.blade.php):

```
@extends('master', ['title' => "Forbidden"])
@section('content')
    <div>You shouldn't be here. This is a 403 error!</div>
@endsection
```

Why is this not working?

Comment: Check your [apache logs](https://serverfault.com/a/886166) to make sure it's not an actual directory permission problem that apache is handling.

Comment: @ourmandave Apache logs show this: `[Sat Aug 18 22:37:33.078666 2018] [autoindex:error] [pid 7688:tid 1952] [client ip:51179] AH01276: Cannot serve directory C:/xampp/htdocs/sqless/public/img/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.pl,index.cgi,index.asp,index.shtml,index.html,index.htm,default.php,default.pl,default.cgi,default.asp,default.shtml,default.html,default.htm,home.php,home.pl,home.cgi,home.asp,home.shtml,home.html,home.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive` What's the next step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel cannot handle this 403 error. The request is not even handled by Laravel in this case.

Depending on your apache configuration, If the there is an existing file or directory matches the requested URI, it will be served. If there is no file/directory, the request will be forwarded to be handled by Laravel. This is the default Laravel configurations as it is defined in Laravel [.htaccess](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/b2d7facfbbd1f01e4dfe523e4b2d7a2a9d85bbc5/public/.htaccess#L18-L20) file.

In your case, the directory `img` exists in the DocumentRoot, and it's served by Apache. You see 403 error because the directory does not have an `index` file.

So, If you want to customize this 403 error page, you have to do it by editing Apache configurations.